# Postulating namespaces in Coq

Tags: coq, agda

I would like to have signatures such that I can postulate inhabitants for them. In Agda it looks like this:

```
record Foo (A : Set) : Set where
  field
    bar : A
    baz : A → A

postulate assumeFoo : Foo ℕ
open Foo assumeFoo
```

The advantage of this technique is that we can conveniently assemble and parameterize large bundles of postulated theories.

In Coq, I can open modules as namespaces and postulate inhabitants of records, but don't know how to do *both* for either. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no exact analog of this feature in Coq. The closest you can get is to use a typeclass. This solves the parameterization issue, but does not provide the same namespace features. Your example would become:

```
Class Foo (A : Type) := {
  bar : A;
  baz : A -> A
}.
```

This declares a record with two fields `bar` and `baz`. What's special about the `Class` command is that Coq has a mechanism for filling in implicit arguments when their type was declared as a class. For instance, here is how we would postulate that `nat` has an instance of `Foo`:

```
Section MySection.

Context {fooNat : Foo nat}.

Check bar.

Check baz bar.

End MySection.
```

Any definitions inside the section would then get an extra `fooNat` parameter once you leave the section.

You can refer to the [Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual023.html) for more references on typeclasses.